# Even some useless stuff would be of use some day

Tags: idioms, expressions, proverbs

Is there any common idiom or expression in English which can convey such a message that: **anything that is of no use, will be used someday for sure**. It is a translated proverb which believes do not underestimate some out-of-use things. It indicates the message that you have to value your belongings and not through everything away.

The only idiom I know in English is:

> - **Keep it seven years and you'll find a use for it**;

But for me, there is something missing in this idiom which is hard to explain. So I think it wouldnt work in this sense. (If you think it works please let me know.)

**Note:** it's not at all about hoarders who don't have the heart to throw away even useless stuff.

Comment: "Keep it seven years and you'll find a use for it" sounds to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: "might come in handy one day" or "might find a use for that one day" are the only phrases I can think of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that is very close to this sentiment—although being a proverb, it's not identical—is [**every dog has its day**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/every+dog+has+its+day):

> [The Free Dictionary]
>
> *Prov.* Everyone gets a chance eventually. *Don't worry, you'll get chosen for the team. Every dog has its day. You may become famous someday. Every dog has his day.*

Although, if interpreted in its usual sense it's talking about people eventually getting a chance, it's still a metaphor, and it would be easily understood in context:

> "This is a useless piece of junk."
>   "Keep it around—it may come in handy sometime. Every dog has its day."

Answer (score 3):

I have commonly heard:

> One man's trash is another man's treasure.

It doesn't have the exact same meaning, but it is similar to what you are looking for. Even if you do not have a use for something, it may have a use to other people. It can therefore also mean that even if you don't obviously have a use for something *now*, it does not mean that it is literally useless, nor does it mean that you won't have a use for it in the future.

I have never heard the "Keep it seven years" idiom.

There's also a common statement that just says the exact thing you're looking for, but it's not a proverb or saying:

> Well, hold onto it; you might find a use for it one day.